# select rows where values equal to column values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table **Table 1** which has 5 columns like this

```
|   ID   |   Name  |   V1   |   V2   |   V3   |
|   1    |    A    |   103  |   507  |   603  |
|   2    |    B    |   514  |   415  |   117  |
|   3    |    C    |   741  |   895  |   854  |
```

and another table **Table 2** which has values like this

```
|  Values |  Rooms  |
|   103   |   ABC   |
|   507   |   DEF   |
|   603   |   GHI   |
|   514   |   JKL   |
|   415   |   MNO   |
|   117   |   PQR   |
```

I want to select Rooms from Table 2 where values are equal to V1, V2 and V3 of multiple rows from Table 1. In short, I want to select V1, V2 and V3 columns values something like this

```
103, 507, 603, 514, 415, 117, 741, 895, 854
```

so I can run a where clause in my select statement for Table 2.

Comment: How does your example data get that output? Why is 103 linked to A, B and C? Please provide a correct sample, because that makes it much easier to understand.

Comment: share the output you want in tabular format. You want to select rooms or V1,V2 and V3 columns?

Comment: "I want to select Rooms from Table 2"  "I want to select V1, V2 and V3 columns values"  What do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
SELECT t2.[Values] FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.V1 = t2.[Values]
                    OR t1.V2 = t2.[Values]
                    OR t1.V3 = t2.[Values]
```

Try this one:

```
SELECT t1.v1,t1.v2,t1.v3 FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.V1 = t2.[Values]
                    OR t1.V2 = t2.[Values]
                    OR t1.V3 = t2.[Values]
```

Comment: @MegaTron , you will get exactly matched values of V1, V2 and V3 columns with the [t2.Values]. I just show t2.[Values] column which will show indirectly the matched values of V1, V2 and V3 columns.

Comment: Your join changes the order of record and sort the result in ascending order while I do not want to change the order of records.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
select t2.Rooms from Table2 t2
where exists
select * from Table1 t1 where t1.V1 = t2.Values
                        or t1.V2 = t2.Values
                        or t1.V3 = t2.Values
```

Comment: Please read the question again: "I want to select V1, V2 and V3 columns values"

Comment: @MegaTron Please read the question again: "I want to select Rooms from Table 2 where values are equal to V1, V2 and V3 of multiple rows from Table 1"

Comment: Even so, we can not provide any answers before the author does not clarify the question. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @Aleksa Milosevic: You have an error in your SQL syntax.

Comment: Maybe you can't. I have no problem understanding what he meant

Comment: I think you should be more polite Aleksa. Also as mentioned Code-Monk you have an error in query